# Div over iframe and white border on internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I’m trying to put a div over a iframe with a youtube video. Everything works as intended in chrome, firefox and opera, but not in Internet Explorer. In IE the div is behind the video and in the video appear a white border.

Here is an [image](https://imageshack.com/i/hlBQAeZDp) of the problem

The code i'm using is this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
//css code 
     <style> 

    html, body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .mainDiv{
        background-color:blue;
        height:350px;
        width:350px;
    }

    .video{
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }

    .front {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        left:120px;
        top:120px;
        background:#f00;
    }
  </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <iframe class="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sItFnGYjhbY?modestbranding=1&version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=sItFnGYjhbY&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
        <div class="front"></div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I’ve tried various solutions that I found but anyone works. Any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Also i found on error I made.
I don't use embed link from video link. That solves the problema of the white borders.
i use ...tube.com/v/sItFnGYjhbY and i have to use ....ube.com/embed/HgkbCm5K45I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE, and plug-ins are window elements. It's impossible to render anything in front of an window element but other window elements.

Solution: Put `div.front` into an iframe as well, order with `z-index`.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it Works!
Any solution about the white border on teh video frame?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `z-index` to tell it the order of stacking:

```
.video{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:1;
}

.front {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:120px;
    top:120px;
    background:#f00;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[More information about z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)